# Inconsistent behavior with Win32 Console API between console emulator

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in the following snippet?

The problem is that this snippet, which is supposed to print "Hello, World!" with colors works exactly as expected when ran in [cmder](https://cmder.app/) with cmd.exe as the shell, but is is completly broken when used in the native cmd.exe terminal emulator or the native PowerShell emulator.
Specifically, the background color is changed, and the reset doesn't work.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fileapi.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  HANDLE h;
  HANDLE hin;
  WORD savedAttr;
} Terminal;

#define FOREGROUND_RGB (FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN)
#define BACKGROUND_RGB (BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN)
#define TRY_OS(expr) if ((expr) == 0) { osError(); }
#define TRY_OR(expr) if ((expr) == 0)

static WORD get_text_attributes(Terminal term)
{
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO c;

  TRY_OR(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(term.h, &c)) {
    return 0x70;
  }

  return c.wAttributes;
}

Terminal getHandle(FILE* in, FILE* out)
{
  Terminal term;

  if ((in == stdin) && (out == stdout)) {
    // grab the current console even if stdin/stdout have been redirected
    term.h =
        CreateFile("CON", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                   0, 0);
    term.hin =
        CreateFile("CON", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,
                   0);
    // term.h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    // term.hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  } else {
    term.h = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(_fileno(out));
    term.hin = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(_fileno(in));
  }

  term.savedAttr = get_text_attributes(term);
  return term;
}

void setFG(Terminal term, int color)
{
  WORD attr = get_text_attributes(term);
  attr &= ~FOREGROUND_RGB;  // clear FG color
  attr &= ~FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;  // clear FG intensity
  attr |= color;

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(term.h, attr);
}

void setBG(Terminal term, int color)
{
  WORD attr = get_text_attributes(term);
  attr &= ~BACKGROUND_RGB;  // clear BG color
  attr &= ~BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;  // clear BG intensity
  attr |= color;

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(term.h, attr);
}

int main()
{
  Terminal term = getHandle(stdin, stdout);

  setFG(term, FOREGROUND_RED);
  WriteConsole(term.h, "Hello, ", 7, NULL, NULL);

  setFG(term, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
  WriteConsole(term.h, "World !\r\n", 9, NULL, NULL);

  // reset style
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(term.h, term.savedAttr);

  return 0;
}
```

I guess I am doing something wrong in my use of the API and cmder is looser about it, but I wrote this whole code by reading the official Microsoft doc, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: Are `setBG()` and `setFG()` both to be called with `color` in the range 0 to 15 as implied by the `assert()` calls? It so, in `setBG()` the line `attr |= color;` should be changed to `attr |= (color << 4);`.

Comment: `WriteConsole(term.h, "Hello, ", 8, NULL, NULL);` seems to be using the wrong length. I count 7 characters in the string, not 8.

Comment: @IanAbbott The assert are wrong actually ! I just missed them when building the simplified example from my actual code. Here I use the colors from the windows header so they should be ok.
Same for the length actually, It was not hard coded in my initial code. Thank catching that, I am editting it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use `Multi-Byte Character Set` in stead of `Unicode Character Set`.

[image]

Or you could try to use wide-character literal, like:

```
    term.h =
        CreateFile(L"CON", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
            0, 0);
    term.hin =
        CreateFile(L"CON", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0,
```

.

```
WriteConsole(term.h, L"Hello, ", 8, NULL, NULL);
```

.

```
WriteConsole(term.h, L"World !\n\r", 9, NULL, NULL);
```

**EDIT:**

Results of running with cmd:[image]

Results of running with visual studio: [image]

Comment: I am actually writing a library, so I want to avoid compiler side configurations, but I think you put me on the right track.

Comment: "avoid compiler side configurations" You could use wide character literal.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: I have added the result in my answer.
If I misunderstood you, please let me know.

Comment: The fact that the style doesn't reset (the background is still grey) is actually my problem. So wide characters doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot to help me understand what do you want to realize?